# Access variables outside the jQuery .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little bit complicated html structure.
I parse it to get this stuff:

```
Option1: value
Option2: value
```

from this like html:

```html
<div class="option" id="option-691">
<span class="required">*</span>
<b>Option:</b><br>
<input type="radio" checked="" id="option-value-1250" value="1250" price="1156.0000" name="option[691]">
<label for="option-value-1250">2,35 xx - 1156.00 </label>
<br>
<input type="radio" onchange="recalculateprice();reloadpr();" id="option-value-1251" value="1251" price="506.0000" price_prefix="" points="0" name="option[691]">
<label for="option-value-1251">900 xx - 506.00</label>
<br>
</div>
```

and this too

```html
<div class="option" id="option-690">
<span class="required">*</span>
<b>Option:</b><br>
<select name="option[690]">
<option price="1156.0000" price_prefix="+" points="0" value="1249">value01
(+1156.00)
</option>
<option price="1156.0000" price_prefix="+" points="0" value="1248">value02
(+1156.00)
</option>
<option price="1156.0000" price_prefix="+" points="0" value="1247">value03
(+1156.00)
</option>
</select>
 </div>
```

And using this I can get data from both types (inputs + selects).

```js
$('#product_options > div.option').each(function() {
 var Opt01 = ( $(this).find('option:selected').parent().parent().find('b').text() + $(this).find('option:selected').text() );
 var Opt02 = ( $(this).find('input:checked').parent().find('b').text() + $(this).find('input:checked').next().text() );

console.log(Opt01);
console.log(Opt02);
 });
```

But, I want to get Opt01 and Opt02 outside the .each() loop. How I can do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In a nutshell I just want to get checked/selected values, which located in different elements.

Answer (score 3):

Variables declared within functions can't be accessed outside of them. Just declare them outside of the loop:

```
var Opt01;
var Opt02;

$('#product_options > div.option').each(function() {
  Opt01 = ( $(this).find('option:selected').parent().parent().find('b').text() + $(this).find('option:selected').text() );
  Opt02 = ( $(this).find('input:checked').parent().find('b').text() + $(this).find('input:checked').next().text() );

  console.log(Opt01);
  console.log(Opt02);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable outside the each loop. Variables declared inside the function can be accessed only from inside. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnwyzj6q/5/)

```
var Opt01, Opt02; 
function find(){
    $('#product_options > div.option').each(function() {
      var option1 = ( $(this).find('option:selected').parent().parent().find('b').text() +              $(this).find('option:selected').text() );
      var option2 = ( $(this).find('input:checked').parent().find('b').text() +      $(this).find('input:checked').next().text() );
      if(option1){ 
          Opt01 = option1;  
          console.log("inside: "+Opt01);
      }
      if(option2){  
          Opt02 = option2; 
          console.log("inside: "+Opt02); 
      }              
  });
  console.log("outside: "+Opt01);
  console.log("outside: "+Opt02);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this already, the problem is - if I trying to get Opt1 +Opt2 outside the loop I get first option only, second variable is empty.

Comment: You are getting second variable as empty because the last value assigned to Opt02 is empty. Updated the code. Try this.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to say that I need to do some extra validation before .each(). May you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/caLj2xbe/
As I think, if I put loop in if statement, then I can access to those variables from whole if {...}

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get Opt01 and Opt02 outside the .each() loop

Since the variables are local in that context (by using *var* keyword), outside of the `each` callback the variables are `undefined`. You could define them outside of the each callback, e.g. `var opt1, opt2;`, but what will happen? In each iteration the values are overridden and the last values win. If the selector returns 1 element then `each` shouldn't be used in the first place.

You could define a function and pass the values to it.

```
$('#product_options > div.option').each(function() {
    var Opt1 = '...';
    var Opt2 = '...';
    doSomething(Opt1, Opt2);
});
```

Or use the `map` method and create an array of objects:

```
var options = $('#product_options > div.option').map(function() {
    var opt01 = '...';
    var opt02 = '...';
    return {
       opt1: opt01,
       opt2: opt02
    }
}).get();
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple,

You have to declare your variables outside of your function as global.
But don't declare only,assign some value
Var opt1=0;

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys. I've added another validation rule before loop and code looks like this, so far. And it works fine:

```js
if ($('#product_options div.option').length) {
  $('#product_options > div.option').each(function () {
//defining
OptionTitle = $(this).find('option:selected').parent().parent().find('b').text();
OptionValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
InputTitle = $(this).find('input:checked').parent().find('b').text();
InputValue = $(this).find('input:checked').next().text();
//
if (OptionTitle != '' && OptionValue != '') {
  Opt01 = (OptionTitle + OptionValue)
}
if (InputTitle != '' && InputValue != '') {
  Opt02 = (InputTitle + InputValue)
}
  });
  //get values outside the loop
console.log('Options detected');
if (typeof Opt01 === 'undefined') {
Opt01 = ''
}
if (typeof Opt02 === 'undefined') {
Opt02 = ''
}
  console.log('Opt01 = ' + Opt01);
  console.log('Opt02 = ' + Opt02);
} 
else {
console.log('Options are empty');
var Opt01 = '';
var Opt02 = '';
 console.log('Opt01 = ' + Opt01);
 console.log('Opt02 = ' + Opt02);
 }
```

Also, fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/caLj2xbe/